# How to limit the depth of Zend_Navigation?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I am creating a categories sidebar using Zend_Navigation. In my bootstrap I am putting in all my pages, products, categories and anything else I can find in the future. I am getting my categories links out using `$navigation->findAllBy('class', 'categories')` which is returning an array of all my categories. This is working and displaying as it should.

Now...

How do I limit the depth of the sub-categories / pages? So that instead of (at the moment) 6 levels of categories and sub-categories, I have (for example) 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->navigation()->menu()->setMaxDepth(2)
```